# Read Django session key cookie from Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, session-cookies

I'm using Django and I need to be able to check if the client has an
active session on the server from a javascript script. Is there a way to check if the client has a valid django session key cookie from javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you request a page from the Django site, it should send you a cookie which should start a session if Django is set up properly. The name of the cookie will be `sessionid`.

To see if this cookie exists you can do `if (document.cookie.indexOf("sessionid") >= 0)`

If you want to see/confirm more details you will have to use an Ajax request to the server.

Comment: I think you need to disable `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` if you want to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY — the main benefit of not exposing it to JS in the browser is that it if someone successfully performs a XSS attack they won’t be able to hijack the session.